# Isn't http keep alive feature against three rule of thumbs: assyncronous, reactive programing and scalability

Tags: http, keep-alive

I know in HTTP 1.1, keep-alive is the default behavior, unless the client explicitly asks the server to close the connection by including a Connection: close header in its request, or the server decides to includes a Connection: close header in its response. I am wondering if this isn't kind of an obstacle in scalability when growning servers horizontaly.

My scenario: we are developing all new services following microservices patterns either in Java or Phyton. It is desarible we can design and implement such way we can increase horizontally. For isntance, I can use docker in order to easily scale up or use Spring Boot Cloud Config. Whatever the phisical host implementation the basic idea is favour scalability.

My understanding: I must keep server and client as musch agnostic as possible and when I set up HTTP Keep Alive I understand there will be advantage while taking use of same http connection (and save some cpu process) but I guess I am forcing the client (eg. another service) to keep using same connection which may downgrade the advantage of several docker instances of same service since I will promote the client to keep consuming the same initial connection.

Assuming my understanding is correct, I assume it is not a good idea since we develop the service providing response that can be reuseable from different consumers with different approaches: some consumers can consume assyncronously or following reactive design paradigms which make me wondering if keeping alive same connection. Let's say in practical terms: the connection used should be free soon as possible in order to really balance the demand over all providers.

***edited after first comment

Let´s assume I have multiple diferent consumer services (CS1, CS2 ... CSn) connecting to a single Load Balance instance (LB) which will forward the request to multiple Dockers with same provider service (D1, D2 ... Dn). Since keep alive is the default behaviour in http 1+, we have keep "alive = true" in all connection (either between Cx and LB or LB and Dx). As far as I know the only advantage to keep alive is save cpu process while opening/closing a connection. If I send Connection:close after each request there is no advantage at all to use keep alive. If I have some logic to send "connection: close" it means I promote LB to keep connected to a specific Dx using exactly the same connection for while, right? (I choose here the word promote because I iguess force might not be the appropriate one since there is time out in keep alive and then LB migh route to another Dx anyway). So I have in some moment C1 -> LB -> D1 alive persisted for while, right? Comming back to my original question, isn't that against the idea of assyncronous/paralelal/reactive paradigm? For instance, I have some scenario where a single consumer service will call another service few times before returning a single answer to a page. Today we are doing it sequentially but if we decide to call in paralalel and depending on first answer therer will be already a answer to a page or we decide to compouse an answer to the page but I don't care the order. The caller service will wait every answers before returning to a ccontroller and the order doesn't matter. Ins't strange I have keep alive = true?

Answer (score 1):

> I am forcing the client (eg. another service) to keep using same connection

You are not *forcing*. The client can easily avoid persistent connections by sending `HTTP/1.0` and/or `Connection: close`. There are many practical HTTP applications that work just like that.

> keep using same connection which may downgrade the advantage of several docker instances of same service since I will promote the client to keep consuming the same initial connection

Assuming your load balancer works well, it will usually distribute  connections evenly across your instances. Of course, this may not work when you only have a few connections altogether, but a few connections can hardly  pose a scalability or performance problem.

Comment: Vasiliy, I edited my question adding an example after your comment. I am still wondering if it is not contraditory use keep alive in above scenario